# ¿Cómo hacer la suma de nodos en un árbol binario?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estoy haciendo un sistema binario en PHP donde tengo que traer una (valga la redundancia) "**Estructura Binaria**" por cada usuario que yo selecciono. La estructura en árbol la traigo con una librería llamada TreeFlex.

Esta estructura ya funciona, la hago mediante querys que presento en mi script y trae los hijos de cada uno de ellos sin problema alguno (solamente necesito traer a pantalla 7 (1 nodo raiz y 6 nodos hijos),puedo traer mas mediante la misma estructura que manejo)

Ahora lo que necesito hacer es un conteo de NODOS (hijos) que tiene abajo cada uno, para después hacer una sumatoria hasta el nivel 3 (muestro imagen), lo eh intentado hacer mediante la funcion de `mysqli_num_rows` por el query que tengo en un while pero no logro traer el numero de nodos por cada uno, siempre me muestra un dos aunque no tenga nada abajo.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $id_b = base64_decode($_GET['id']);
        $id = $id_b . "-A";
        $query_amigo = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM arbol WHERE  id_new_socio = '" . $id . "'");
        $nivel = mysqli_fetch_array($query_amigo);
    
        $id_socio =  $nivel['id_new_socio'];
        $nombre =  $nivel['name'];
        $paterno = $nivel['a_p'];
        $materno = $nivel['a_m'];
    }
    
    if (!isset($_GET['id'])) {
        header("location: amigos.php");
    }
    
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    
    <head>
        <?php include("head.php"); ?>
    </head>
    
    <body class="hold-transition <?php echo $skin; ?> sidebar-mini">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <header class="main-header">
                <?php include("main-header.php"); ?>
            </header>
            <!-- Left side column. contains the logo and sidebar -->
            <aside class="main-sidebar">
                <?php include("main-sidebar.php"); ?>
            </aside>
            <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
                <?php if ($permisos_ver == 1) { ?>
                    <section class="content-header">
                        <div id="resultados_ajax"></div>
                        <h1>Linea De Negocio <b>A.</b></h1>
                        <h1> <?php echo $nombre . " " . $paterno . " " . $materno; ?> </h1>
    
                    </section>
                    <!-- Main content -->
    
                    <section class="content">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="box">
                                    <div class="box box-solid">
                                        <div class="box-header with-border"></div>
                                        <div class="tf-tree center" style="font-size: 20px;">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li>
                                                    <!--CABECERA DEL ARBOL-->
                                                    <span class="tf-nc text-center" readonly onmousedown="return false;"> <?php echo $nombre . " " . $paterno . " " . $materno . " #" . $id_socio ?></span>
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <!--NIVEL 2-->
                                                        <?php
    
                                                        $query_hijo = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM arbol WHERE  id_patrocinador = '$id'");
    
                                                        while ($segundo_nivel = mysqli_fetch_array($query_hijo)) {
                                                            $id_hijo =      $segundo_nivel['id_new_socio'];
                                                            $nombre_hijo =  $segundo_nivel['name'];
                                                            $paterno_hijo = $segundo_nivel['a_p'];
                                                            $materno_hijo = $segundo_nivel['a_m'];
    
                                                        ?>
                                                            <li>
                                                                <span class="tf-nc" readonly onmousedown="return false;"><?php echo $nombre_hijo . " " . $paterno_hijo . " #" . $id_hijo
                                                                                                                            ?> </span>
    
                                                                <ul>
                                                                    <?php
                                                                    $query_hijo_dos = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM arbol WHERE  id_patrocinador = '$id_hijo'");
    
                                                                    while ($tercer_nivel = mysqli_fetch_array($query_hijo_dos)) {
                                                                        $id_hijo_dos =      $tercer_nivel['id_new_socio'];
                                                                        $nombre_hijo_dos =  $tercer_nivel['name'];
                                                                        $paterno_hijo_dos = $tercer_nivel['a_p'];
                                                                        $materno_hijo_dos = $tercer_nivel['a_m'];
                                                                    ?>
                                                                        <li>
                                                                            <span class="tf-nc" readonly onmousedown="return false;"><?php echo $nombre_hijo_dos . " " . $paterno_hijo_dos . " #" . $id_hijo_dos
                                                                                                                                        ?></span>
    
    
                                                                        </li>
                                                                    <?php } ?>
                                                                </ul>
                                                            </li>
    
                                                        <?php } ?>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </li>
    
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                        <!---->
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </section><!-- /.content -->
    
                <?php
                } else {
                ?>
                    <section class="content">
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <h3>Acceso denegado! </h3>
                            <p>No cuentas con los permisos necesario para acceder a este módulo.</p>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
            </div><!-- /.content-wrapper -->
            <?php include("footer.php"); ?>
        </div><!-- ./wrapper -->
        <?php include("js.php"); ?>
        <script src="dist/js/amigos.js"></script>
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Imagen de muestra de la estructura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comparto la estructura de como tengo la BD, las letras son solo para identificar en que linea de negocio están (existen 3 (A,B,C)), es por eso que necesito el contador, para identificar las personas que tiene 6 personas abajo de ellas para poder aperturar una segunda linea (B) o tercera (C) si ya cumplió con la segunda, la columna `id_new_socio` el la persona del nodo e `id_patrocinador` es de la persona que cuelga el nodo (papá).

| id | id_new_socio | id_patrocinador | name | a_p | a_m |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1-A | 0 | Jose Luis | Huerta | Lopez |
| 2 | 2-A | 1-A | Maria | Mercedes | Perez |
| 3 | 3-A | 1-A | David | Perez | Sosa |
| 4 | 4-A | 2-A | Miguel | Martinez | Soto |
| 5 | 5-A | 2-A | Cecilia | Baez | Saenz |
| 6 | 6-A | 3-A | Tomas | Santos | Lopez |
| 7 | 7-A | 3-A | Claudia | Romero | Sanchez |

Comment: Compartí la estructura de la tabla, para ver como se almacenan los nodos.

Comment: @nachospiu listo, espero que me puedas ayudar

Comment: La versión de MySql es la 8.0? o una anterior? Lo ideal es que no subas imágenes, con está web [tablesgenerator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#) podés construir las tablas markdown.

Comment: La versión que me marca es esta: 10.4.14-MariaDB

Comment: Tengo una idea de como hacerlo, pero tengo que terminar de entenderlo bien. Las lineas A, B y C no se tocan (son paralelas)? o sea si un nodo está en una linea A, todos sus padres están en la misma linea A (y no puede haber nodos B y C en esa linea)?

Comment: Te explico un poco sobre las líneas, una vez que un NODO padre tiene 6 abajo de el (dos hijos y 4 nietos (dos por cada hijo)), se le puede aperturar una nueva linea de negocio (B) y si este ahora en vez de tener 6 tiene 12 se le apertura (C), pero siempre van a estar en la misma tabla de ARBOL

Comment: Y si  puede haber padres (B o C) de hijos (A) y viceversa, padres (A) e hijos (B o C)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ver si está query te sirve.

Le pasas el id (o podría ser también el id_new_socio) del nodo en el que estás, y te retorna todos los nodos hijos (una fila para el nodo actual y una por cada nodo hijo, y los hijos de los hijos, etc. hasta que llega a los nodos que ya no tienen hijos).

```
WITH recursive nodos AS (
   SELECT id, id_new_socio AS nodo, id_patrocinador AS padre 
   FROM t
   WHERE id = 3
   
   UNION ALL
   
   SELECT t.id, t.id_new_socio AS nodo, t.id_patrocinador AS padre 
   FROM nodos n
   INNER JOIN t ON t.id_patrocinador = n.nodo
)

SELECT * 
FROM nodos
ORDER BY id;
```

Para el conjunto de datos de ejemplo de tu tabla y id = 3 retorna:

| id | nodo | padre |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 3-A | 1-A |
| 6 | 6-A | 3-A |
| 7 | 7-A | 3-A |

Si reemplazas el JOIN por este otro: `INNER JOIN t ON  t.id_new_socio = n.padre` obtienes todos los nodos padres del nodo actual (el que pasas como parámetro), o sea regenera el arbol hacia arriba (en sentido inverso a la query anterior).

Si quieres obtener el arbol completo desde el nodo raiz, con el nivel en el que se encuentra cada nodo:

```
WITH recursive nodos AS (
   SELECT id, id_new_socio AS nodo, id_patrocinador AS padre, 1 AS nivel
   FROM t
   WHERE id = 1
   
   UNION ALL
   
   SELECT t.id, t.id_new_socio AS nodo, t.id_patrocinador AS padre, n.nivel + 1 AS nivel
   FROM nodos n
   INNER JOIN t ON t.id_patrocinador = n.nodo
)

SELECT * 
FROM nodos
ORDER BY id;
```

Si solo quieres obtener los nodos hijos directos, solo los del próximo nivel, entonces esta query es mucho mas eficiente (en la claúsula SELECT puedes seleccionar los campos que deses, y el parámetro parametro_id_new_socio es el id_new_socio del nodo actual. Si haces un `SELECT count(*)` te retornará la cantidad de nodos hijos directos):

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE id_patrocinador = parametro_id_new_socio;
```

Para generar el arbol recursivamente con php, html, css y treeflex:

```
//$nodos = //El arreglo que retorna alguna de las queries anteriores.

function getArbol($nodos, $nodoActual) {
    $res = "";
    $res .= "<li>";
    $res .= "<span class='tf-nc'>{$nodoActual['nodo']}</span>";
    $cantHijos = 0;

    foreach($nodos as $nodo) {
        if($nodoActual['nodo'] == $nodo['padre']) {
            $cantHijos++;

            $res .= $cantHijos == 1 ? "<ul>" : "";

            $res .= getArbol($nodos, $nodo);
        }
    }

    $res .= $cantHijos > 0 ? "</ul>" : "";

    $res .= "</li>";

    return $res;
}

$arbol = getArbol($nodos, $nodos[0]);

echo "<div class='tf-tree'>";
echo "<ul>";

echo $arbol;

echo "</ul>";
echo "</div>";
```

```css
.tf-tree{font-size:16px;overflow:auto}.tf-tree *{box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;padding:0}.tf-tree ul{display:inline-flex}.tf-tree li{align-items:center;display:flex;flex-direction:column;flex-wrap:wrap;padding:0 1em;position:relative}.tf-tree li ul{margin:2em 0}.tf-tree li li:before{border-top:.0625em solid #000;content:"";display:block;height:.0625em;left:-.03125em;position:absolute;top:-1.03125em;width:100%}.tf-tree li li:first-child:before{left:calc(50% - .03125em);max-width:calc(50% + .0625em)}.tf-tree li li:last-child:before{left:auto;max-width:calc(50% + .0625em);right:calc(50% - .03125em)}.tf-tree li li:only-child:before{display:none}.tf-tree li li:only-child>.tf-nc:before,.tf-tree li li:only-child>.tf-node-content:before{height:1.0625em;top:-1.0625em}.tf-tree .tf-nc,.tf-tree .tf-node-content{border:.0625em solid #000;display:inline-block;padding:.5em 1em;position:relative}.tf-tree .tf-nc:before,.tf-tree .tf-node-content:before{top:-1.03125em}.tf-tree .tf-nc:after,.tf-tree .tf-nc:before,.tf-tree .tf-node-content:after,.tf-tree .tf-node-content:before{border-left:.0625em solid #000;content:"";display:block;height:1em;left:calc(50% - .03125em);position:absolute;width:.0625em}.tf-tree .tf-nc:after,.tf-tree .tf-node-content:after{top:calc(100% + .03125em)}.tf-tree .tf-nc:only-child:after,.tf-tree .tf-node-content:only-child:after,.tf-tree>ul>li>.tf-nc:before,.tf-tree>ul>li>.tf-node-content:before{display:none}.tf-tree.tf-gap-sm li{padding:0 .6em}.tf-tree.tf-gap-sm li>.tf-nc:before,.tf-tree.tf-gap-sm li>.tf-node-content:before{height:.6em;top:-.6em}.tf-tree.tf-gap-sm li>.tf-nc:after,.tf-tree.tf-gap-sm li>.tf-node-content:after{height:.6em}.tf-tree.tf-gap-sm li ul{margin:1.2em 0}.tf-tree.tf-gap-sm li li:before{top:-.63125em}.tf-tree.tf-gap-sm li li:only-child>.tf-nc:before,.tf-tree.tf-gap-sm li li:only-child>.tf-node-content:before{height:.6625em;top:-.6625em}.tf-tree.tf-gap-lg li{padding:0 1.5em}.tf-tree.tf-gap-lg li>.tf-nc:before,.tf-tree.tf-gap-lg li>.tf-node-content:before{height:1.5em;top:-1.5em}.tf-tree.tf-gap-lg li>.tf-nc:after,.tf-tree.tf-gap-lg li>.tf-node-content:after{height:1.5em}.tf-tree.tf-gap-lg li ul{margin:3em 0}.tf-tree.tf-gap-lg li li:before{top:-1.53125em}.tf-tree.tf-gap-lg li li:only-child>.tf-nc:before,.tf-tree.tf-gap-lg li li:only-child>.tf-node-content:before{height:1.5625em;top:-1.5625em}.tf-tree li.tf-dotted-children .tf-nc:after,.tf-tree li.tf-dotted-children .tf-nc:before,.tf-tree li.tf-dotted-children .tf-node-content:after,.tf-tree li.tf-dotted-children .tf-node-content:before{border-left-style:dotted}.tf-tree li.tf-dotted-children li:before{border-top-style:dotted}.tf-tree li.tf-dotted-children>.tf-nc:before,.tf-tree li.tf-dotted-children>.tf-node-content:before{border-left-style:solid}.tf-tree li.tf-dashed-children .tf-nc:after,.tf-tree li.tf-dashed-children .tf-nc:before,.tf-tree li.tf-dashed-children .tf-node-content:after,.tf-tree li.tf-dashed-children .tf-node-content:before{border-left-style:dashed}.tf-tree li.tf-dashed-children li:before{border-top-style:dashed}.tf-tree li.tf-dashed-children>.tf-nc:before,.tf-tree li.tf-dashed-children>.tf-node-content:before{border-left-style:solid}
```

```html
<div class='tf-tree' style="font-size: 10px;">
  <ul>
    <li><span class='tf-nc'>1-A</span>
      <ul>
        <li><span class='tf-nc'>2-A</span>
          <ul>
            <li><span class='tf-nc'>4-A</span></li>
            <li><span class='tf-nc'>5-A</span></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span class='tf-nc'>3-A</span>
          <ul>
            <li><span class='tf-nc'>6-A</span>
              <ul>
                <li><span class='tf-nc'>9-A</span></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><span class='tf-nc'>7-A</span>
              <ul>
                <li><span class='tf-nc'>10-A</span>
                  <ul>
                    <li><span class='tf-nc'>11-A</span></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><span class='tf-nc'>8-A</span></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Si reemplazas el JOIN por este otro `INNER JOIN t ON  t.id_new_socio = n.padre` obtienes todos los nodos padres del nodo actual (el que pasas como parámetro).

Comment: Al hacer las queries a la base de datos te recomiento utilizar [Prepared statment](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php) para prevenir SQL Injections.

Comment: Si necesitas solo los hijos directos (del próximos nivel) podés filtrar en la última query donde padre = id_new_socio del nodo actual (el parámetro).

Comment: Hola de nuevo, tendras algun correo en el que te pueda contactar, tu respuesta que me diste me sirvio (conforme a lo que me dijiste en tu ultimo comentario), ya puedo traer el numero de nodos que hay abajo de cada nodo padre, pero ahora tengo un problema al querer sumarlos (esto ya en el codigo)

Comment: Mañana te contacto.

Comment: [Escribime acá](https://chattory.com/?chat=589154).