# Como hacer un COUNT en un CASE?

Tags: mysql, sql

Intento hacer un select count como condicion de un CASE en la base de datos con el siguiente schema:

| N | P |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 6 | 8 |
| 9 | 8 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 8 | 5 |
| 5 | null |

Intenté:

```
SELECT N, (CASE P
            WHEN NULL THEN 'ROOT'
            WHEN (SELECT COUNT N > 1) THEN 'INNER'
            ELSE 'LEAF'
   END) AS t FROM BST
```

Pero me devuele un error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 7: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '> 1) THEN 'INNER'
            ELSE 'LEAF'
   END) AS t FROM BST' at line 3
```

Comment: Tienes que usar paréntesis para COUNT(), intenta así: `WHEN (SELECT COUNT(N) > 1) THEN 'INNER'`

Comment: No me explico lo que quieres contar... quizás debas explicarlo tu, porque el problema es de sintaxis, si, pero la sintaxis correcta depende de qué es lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: ¿En realidad es necesario usar una imagen para mostrar los datos? Una lista de texto se vería mucho mejor...

Comment: Parece que está tratando de sacar el tipo de nodo en un arbol binario de búsqueda. N parece el valor del nodo y P el nodo padre. Por eso si P es null tiene que poner ROOT al ser la raíz, pero para que sea una hoja (LEAF) o un nodo itermedio (INNER) no se yo si está bien esa condición. La condición para que un nodo sea hoja es que ningún otro nodo le tenga como padre, y la condición para que sea un nodo intermedio es que algún nodo le tenga como padre y que él a su vez tenga padre (P <> null). ¿Puedes confirmar esto @Revolucion for Monica?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías hacer algo así para obtener el resultado que querés:

```
SELECT a1.nodo,
   CASE WHEN count(a2.nodo) > 0 THEN
      CASE WHEN count(a1.padre) > 0 THEN 'INNER' ELSE 'ROOT' END 
   ELSE 
       'LEAF' 
   END AS tipo_nodo

FROM arbol AS a1
LEFT JOIN arbol AS a2 ON a1.nodo = a2.padre
GROUP BY a1.nodo
ORDER BY a1.nodo;
```

Otra forma de hacerlo:

Para obtener los nodos hojas de un arbol (estructura de datos con herencia) deberías hacer algo así:

```
SELECT *
FROM arbol AS a1
LEFT JOIN arbol AS a2 ON a1.nodo = a2.padre
WHERE a2.nodo IS NULL;
```

Para obtener los nodos intermedios podés usar la misma query con pequeñas modificaciones:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a1.nodo
FROM arbol AS a1
INNER JOIN arbol AS a2 ON a1.nodo = a2.padre
WHERE a1.padre IS NOT NULL;
```

Luego puedes hacer un UNION de ambas queries y otro UNION incluyendo al nodo raiz.

Ten en cuenta que trabajar con arboles es sinónimo de trabajar con recursión. Esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/440772/218615) te puede servir.